# Google-apps-script row height when filtering

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a google-apps-script datatable with a StringFilter to be able to filter rows based on the content of one of the columns. The problem is that when I use the filter, the row height changes to fill the whole table. I would like row height to stay unchanged, as it is not user-friendly specially when you filter and you only get one or two results.

If you use the code [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/string-filter-builder) that Google provides in the developers page, you will see the problem:

What should I change so that row height remains unchanged?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checked that example and you are right, every row changes to fit the table. Also the example uses [UI service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/) which is deprecated. I tried using the [Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en) and was able to provide different attributes to the chart and even accomplish what you mentioned.

To run the chart also from Apps script you will need the function:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Then you have to create a html file called "index" (or other name you want) and there you will create the html and javascript code.

```js
      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a bar chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.      
      function drawDashboard() {
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, .25],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, .5],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],
      ]); 
      
        drawChart(data)
      }

      
       function drawChart(data) {

       
        // Create a dashboard.        
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'StringFilter',
            containerId: 'filter_div',
            options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Motivation Level'
               }
        });

        
        
        // Define a table
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'Table',
          dataTable: data,
          containerId: 'table_div',
          options: {
          width: '400px'
               }
         });
       
        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'ColumnChart',
        // so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        
        dashboard.bind([stringFilter], [table]);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
     <div id="dashboard_div">
    
     <h2>Chart Data</h2>
     
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <br />
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="table_div"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

When creating the Table, notice that I only defined the 'width' of the table and not the height. With this the height gets fixed dynamically.